# mysql table column update

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am trying to update Registered_User_Contact table

```
select t1.username , t2.username, t1.registered_user_id, t2.registered_user_id from Registered_User_Contact t2 inner join Registered_User t1 on t1.username = t2.username;

-----------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| username   | username   | registered_user_id | registered_user_id |
+------------+------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| bose       | bose       |                  1 |               NULL |
| chiragjain | chiragjain |                  2 |               NULL |
| mike1      | mike1      |                  3 |               NULL
```

this is my SQL command:

```
UPDATE Registered_User_Contact set t2.registered_user_id = t1.registered_user_id from Registered_User t1 inner join Registered_User_Contact t2 on t1.username = t2.username;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for an update join is off.  Try the following instead:

```
UPDATE Registered_User_Contact t1
INNER JOIN Registered_User t2
    ON t1.username = t2.username
SET t1.registered_user_id = t2.registered_user_id;
```